# Can't Change Height of NavigationBar in NavigationController (it's much wider than normal)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a NavigationController extending from a master TabBarController and extending a ViewController and VC extends to 2x TableView (so, TabBar -> NavigationController -> ViewController -> 2xTableView[with .xib] ). I had to add Navigation Bar to the Navigation Controller to make it work in the viewController, thus works in both tableviews (because I use [Instagram-style swipe](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uacaps/ResourceRepo/master/PageMenu/PageMenuDemoSegmentedControlGif.gif) by using [PageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu)). Now, I can see the navigation bar. (Please note that I had to uncheck `Translucent` on navigation bar on Storyboard to make it visible)

However, it's quite wide, so I am trying to narrow the height. I have tried several answers that I've found online, but no luck for me. First, I tried adding constraints to Navigation Bar (in NavCont) but, when I click on the constraints, everything is disabled (...but for example, when I change the colour of Navigation Bar from storyboard, it works.)

[image]

Also, in my ViewController (where I link to TableView [using this code](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu/blob/master/Demos/Demo%205/PageMenuDemoSegmentedControl/PageMenuDemoSegmentedControl/ViewController.swift)), so I can use these and customise Navigation Bar, however when I try

```
// These works
self.title = "GLOBAL"      
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]

// Neither works for Height
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height = 200
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.y = -50
```

The height of Navigation Bar I want to achieve (and achieved for another UIView, by simply dragging Navigation bar to view on Storyboard):

[image]

This is how it looks

[image]

Comment: I don't think apple wants the navigation bar's height to change

Comment: @HaydenHolligan Please check the question, I have just added screenshots. (Also, no idea why it got down-voted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> achieved for another UIView, by simply dragging Navigation bar to view on Storyboard

Yes, but that's the difference - all the difference in the world. You can do anything you want with *your* navigation bar. But the height of the navigation bar owned and vended by a UINavigationController is not up to you. It is not your navigation bar and you should abandon all hope of changing its size; the navigation controller is in charge, not you.

Comment: I'm not saying that this would not be desirable; file a bug report with Apple if you want them to change the way this works. But you also need to accept that this is how it _does_ work.

Comment: Ah, thanks for saving me hours of research. Maybe it's better to just accept it like that.

Comment: I've tried subclassing UINavigationController and all kinds of tricks, but it's just not worth it. If this is really important to you, write your own parent view controller. :)

Comment: If it's NavController (with Navbar) -> ViewController, you suggest me to add a new ViewController (so have navCon -> ViewCon(add header) -> ViewCont that extends to views, and add the navBar to the new ViewController I added? Thanks

Comment: It would be a lot of work but you could essentially write something that behaves just like a UINavigationController if you wanted to. But is it really worth it? Just let the navbar be the height that it is, I'd say.